# @min annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I need to make impossible to set negative value to certain fields. I use annotation

```
@Min(value = 0, message = "Amount Can't Be negative")
private BigDecimal amount;
```

But it does nothing  - it is still possible to set and save negative values.

I'm using Spring MVC + JPA to save transactions.

I googled a lot couldn't find any solution that helped me. please help.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

My services are transnational and sometimes objects are saved even not having gone throw my default save function. So is there any way to make validate automatically before any transaction will be committed?

Comment: Your `@Min` is just like a law, it needs something to enforce it, like a validator. Do you validate the object? Where?

Comment: How should I validate it?

Comment: Refer section 2.2.1 in the documentation. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-obtaining-validator You will get an instance of a validator and if you validate your object using this validator, a set of constraint violations would be generated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention you are using Spring MVC,you need to validate your bean.

You can use @Valid in RequestMapping with your bean like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public String create(@Valid YourBean yourBean, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap)
```

Or

you can manually call validator like

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(yourBean);
```

For more information follow [this](http://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) link.

Answer (score 1):

When annotations are not working, be sure you have a 'getter' for you instance variable.

for example:

```
@Min(value = 0, message = "Amount Can't Be negative")
private BigDecimal amount;
    
public BigDecimal getAmount() {
     return amount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this one actually worked for me!